# How to convert this PHP code to normal look?

Tags: php, obfuscation, global, decode

How to convert this PHP code to normal look?
code starting `$GLOBALS['_1838807304_']=Array('strtolower','' .'file' .'_ex' .'ist' .'s','' .'mt_rand','f' .'ile_' .'e' .'x' .'ist' .'s','h' .'e' .'a' .'der','define','' .'po' .'s','mb_internal_e' .'nc' .'oding','define','' .'di' .'rname','' .'d' .'efine','' .'s' .'es' .'sio' .'n_s' .'t' .'art','strpo' .'s','preg_replace','cou' .'nt','h' .'ead' .'er','o' .'b' .'_sta' .'rt',`

Full source here [[Source Code]](http://ideone.com/Fmnm8)

Comment: That's some stupid obfuscation.

Comment: The person who wrote that shouldn't really be allowed to be next to a computer.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
print_r($GLOBALS['_1838807304_']);
```

Or better yet:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($GLOBALS['_1838807304_'], true) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo implode($GLOBALS['_1838807304_']);
```

should implode the array and return the array's contents as one string